# Animation in blackberry with several Images

Tags: animation, blackberry

I want to display a number of images in the same position so that it looks like animation. these images should come one after other within microsecond at the moment when the screen loads

Comment: Have you tried using a bitmapfield, a timer and then setting the bitmap in the timer?

Comment: Now, I understand you want to do an high-performance application but a microsecond is one millionth of a second, that would mean 10^6 frames per second! :O [100 Hz would suffice for any reasonable need](http://www.100fps.com/how_many_frames_can_humans_see.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very good example of what you want to do on the supports forum knowledge base article [Display an animatedGif](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Display-an-animated-GIF/ta-p/445014)

Comment: For this to work, the images has to be combined into a gif animation. Saggi wants to display a number of images rather than one gif animation.

Answer (score 1):

See the progress animations section of the BlackBerry knowledgebase article "[Implement advanced buttons, fields, and managers](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276)"

It has a working code sample for slicing up an image of concatenated frames, and displaying each one for a period of time to create a progress animation.